# How to animate div from left to right on clicking on link?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have 4 divs i want to show only one div at a time for that I am using the following code.It is working properly now I want to add animation to my div. 
On clicking on any link, div should be moving from left to right.
This is my working [**link**](http://jsfiddle.net/xrcwrn/R5pBX/)

It should be [**slide like**](http://wowslider.com/jquery-slider-carousel-mac-stack-demo.html)

This is my html code

```
<div id="div1">
  This is div 1
</div>
<div id="div2">
    This is div 2

</div>
<div id="div3">
   This is div 3
</div>
<div id="div4">
  This is div4
</div>
<div id="post_links"> 
  <span id="show1" class="post_active_link">Div1</span>
 <span id="show2">Div2</span>
 <span id="show3">Div3</span>
 <span id="show4">Div4</span>

</div>
```

This is jquery code

```
     $(document).on('click', '#show1', function (event) {
               $('#div1').show();
              $('#div2').hide();
                 $('#div3').hide();
                $('#div4').hide();
 $('#show1').addClass('post_active_link');
 $('#show2').removeClass('post_active_link');
 $('#show3').removeClass('post_active_link');
  $('#show4').removeClass('post_active_link');

           });


            $(document).on('click', '#show2', function (event) {

           $('#div1').hide();
           $('#div2').show();
          $('#div3').hide();
          $('#div4').hide();
      $('#show1').removeClass('post_active_link');
      $('#show2').addClass('post_active_link');
      $('#show3').removeClass('post_active_link');
      $('#show4').removeClass('post_active_link');



         });

          $(document).on('click', '#show3', function (event) {
           $('#div1').hide();
            $('#div2').hide();
            $('#div3').show();
           $('#div4').hide();
    $('#show1').removeClass('post_active_link');
    $('#show2').removeClass('post_active_link');
    $('#show3').addClass('post_active_link');
    $('#show4').removeClass('post_active_link');
             });


           $(document).on('click', '#show4', function (event) {
              $('#div1').hide();
            $('#div2').hide();
              $('#div3').hide();
              $('#div4').show();
      $('#show1').removeClass('post_active_link');
      $('#show2').removeClass('post_active_link');
      $('#show3').removeClass('post_active_link');
      $('#show4').addClass('post_active_link');
           });
```

This is my css code

```
.post_active_link{
    background:#666666;
   }
#div1{
    display:block;
    padding:50px;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
}
#div2,#div3,#div4{
    display:none;
   padding:50px;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
}
#post_links{
    margin-top:10px; 
}
#show1,#show2,#show3,#show4{
    font-weight:bold;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:10px;

}
```

Comment: Just so i may sleep at night i m re-factoring your existing code. Be done in a minute.

Comment: You repeat your code 4 times, here's a better way to do it **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R5pBX/6/)**

Comment: As for the animation, can you be a bit more descriptive so i can make it generic.

Comment: While clicking on link it should shown like image slide show(left to right)

Comment: It should shown like here show [image slider](http://wowslider.com/jquery-slider-carousel-mac-stack-demo.html)

Comment: Got some work to finish up if noone answers you by then i ll write it up it's easy.

Comment: Ok waiting for some great answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).on('click', '#show1', function (event) {
    $('#div1').animate({width: 'show'},"slow");
    $('#div2').hide();
    $('#div3').hide();
    $('#div4').hide();
    $('#show1').addClass('post_active_link');
    $('#show2').removeClass('post_active_link');
    $('#show3').removeClass('post_active_link');
    $('#show4').removeClass('post_active_link');
});

$(document).on('click', '#show2', function (event) {
    $('#div1').hide();
    $('#div2').animate({width: 'show'},"slow");
    $('#div3').hide();
    $('#div4').hide();
    $('#show1').removeClass('post_active_link');
    $('#show2').addClass('post_active_link');
    $('#show3').removeClass('post_active_link');
    $('#show4').removeClass('post_active_link');
});

$(document).on('click', '#show3', function (event) {
    $('#div1').hide();
    $('#div2').hide();
    $('#div3').animate({width: 'show'},"slow");
    $('#div4').hide();
    $('#show1').removeClass('post_active_link');
    $('#show2').removeClass('post_active_link');
    $('#show3').addClass('post_active_link');
    $('#show4').removeClass('post_active_link');
});


$(document).on('click', '#show4', function (event) {
    $('#div1').hide();
    $('#div2').hide();
    $('#div3').hide();
    $('#div4').animate({width: 'show'},"slow");
    $('#show1').removeClass('post_active_link');
    $('#show2').removeClass('post_active_link');
    $('#show3').removeClass('post_active_link');
    $('#show4').addClass('post_active_link');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

So far you have the grey active state on whichever link has been clicked, and are removing post_active_link class and adding it to the next link.

What you want to be doing is having that permanently in place, and then animating it instead of removing and adding to the next click. You could do this by animating its margin-left so it moves across to the relevant place. So on click you would do something like:

```
$(".post_active_link").animate({
    marginLeft: '-=50px'
}, 'slow');
```

Where 50px is the relevant distance until the link that was clicked has gone grey.

Answer (score 0):

As promised i have refactored and added the animation to your code:

**The Js**

```
$("#post_links").on('click', 'span', function () {
    var target = "#div" + $(this).data('target');
    console.log("click");
    $(target).show().animate({
        width: 400
    }, 600).siblings().css("width", "0px").hide();
    $(this).addClass('post_active_link').siblings().removeClass('post_active_link');
});
```

**The Css**

```
#div2, #div3, #div4 {
    display:none;
    padding:50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width:0;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

And added a wrapper to your divs in order to contain and target them.
**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R5pBX/9/)**

Comment: Thanks for reply. It should be (like)[http://wowslider.com/jquery-slider-carousel-mac-stack-demo.html]

Comment: @Manish Oh that's a different story, you ll need to position them absolutely and have the container set at overflow hidden, on click you move their left and right position.